# Passing argument from psql command invoked from batch or shell to a .sql file postgres

Tags: oracle, bash, postgresql, batch-file

Scenerio is like that

I am calling a .sql file runtest.sql and is seeting a variable through -v command

```
psql.exe -w -f  D:\testfolder1\runtest.sql  -v v1='test' -o D:\testfolder1\test1.txt
```

content of runtest.sql is

```
select :v1

\COPY ( select 2+3 )TO c:\:v1.txt;
```

the first command is working as per my expectation v1 is printed as test

but the second command od copy is giving error :v1 is not defined . i want to make a file with run time parameteres passed to it